# This tag has been [script]ed out of existence

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

**Update:**

<del>Already over 800</del> Now reaching <del>1k</del> 2k questions and still rising weekly. Judging by the votes on this post, *can we get rid of this tag?* I would also claim that blacklisting is in place as this tag is likely to return even after burnination (should it happen).

---

Some time ago I stumbled upon the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) tag. At that time, there were just a couple of questions and since it seemed unnecessary - I removed it.

Now, about a month later, this tag already hosts 400+ questions (and growing)! I think this tag is not relevant and might be harmful. Let me explain:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

This tag doesn't help to describe the question in any way. It doesn't give us any information about the real content of the question, looking at it from the home page. It can apply to many (all?) languages and be a part of many frameworks/tools/etc...

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Well... yes. Sure, script/scripting is quite strongly programming-related, but bear with me to the next point and I'm sure you'll let this one slide...

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

NO. One of our main requirements here on the site is for askers to provide a ***minimal** reproducible example*. In that sense, any code in a question is basically a script - a short snippet we can copy-paste and run. As answerers, it doesn't change anything to us if this code is part of a script, a package, or a cooking recipe. ***This tag adds no meaningful information whatsoever.*** It is basically like having a tag for [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code) or [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/program)...

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Different people might have a slightly different definition of what a script is.

**Is it harmful?**

I would claim that this tag is also harmful to some degree. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398919/find-questions-with-only-the-script-tag) shows the questions that are singly-tagged [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script). While most are not top-notch as-is, the fact that the OP had the suggestion for this tag hurts them from getting to proper audiences for their question. Had they not had the option of using this tag, they would either have to look for another more fitting one, or deem their question off-topic.

Another point that comes up as a burnination criteria; **can someone be an expert in [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script)?** The tags that appear in conjunction with [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) range from Python, JavaScript, C# to HTML, shell scripts, and VB with bash appearing most, less than 20% of the questions as can be seen [in this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?tagname=script) (credit to zcoop98). I doubt anyone can be an expert in all those and I doubt anyone will ever benefit from watching this tag (apart from closing its off-topic questions...).

Comment: That's an awfully broad tag that does not describe anything but that the question asks something about an unknown script - sounds like a meta-tag. I'd say burn it.

Comment: _"It is basically like having a tag `code` or `program`..."_ I think this is the only argument we need to make to warrant the burnination of `script`... It's so incredibly broad, I'm surprised there's no _"Yo momma"_  joke in this question.

Comment: For the record, there's a utility named [`script(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html) that creates typescripts for terminal sessions. Given the current usage of the tag, however, I would say it's irrelevant and we should proceed with burninating.

Comment: There is also `<script>` tags but as you said, according to the usage it's irrelevant and also I don't think it warrants its own tag. Actually, [[tag:div]] is a synonym of `html` but I think that doing the same with `script` will have devastating effects...

Comment: Often this tag doesn't add anything if programming language is a script language itself, e.g. [`[batch-script]+[script]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file+script), [`[javascript]+[script]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+script), etc. However, when asking a question about organizing script in a non-script language X, I suspect this tag will do a good job to narrow down search results. What would you do with [`[c#]+[script]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+script)? Not a [tag:unityscript], most of questions are about concept in unity.

Comment: @Sinatr: _"organizing script in a non-script language X"_ Then tag it with the scripting language's name, and the non-scripting language's name... The `script` tag really doesn't add any meaning there.

Comment: @Cerbrus, if scripting language is known (e.g [tag:lua]), then sure. But what if is not known or question is about choosing the right one, implementing one, etc.? We have [tag:functional-programming] and then [tag:haskell] or [tag:f#]. And similarly [tag:script] and [tag:batch-script] or [tag:javascript]. I think we should let the tag stay, but think about and add its usage guidance.

Comment: @Sinatr: `batch-script` and `javascript` are _languages_. `script` is just a _concept_. If there's a scripting language out there that doesn't have a tag yet, then a tag should be created when it's necessary on a question.  `functional-programming` is a methodology that has distinct rules. All of the counter-examples you've provided are well defined, especially compared to `script`. There is _no_ situation where `script` is ___the___ tag to apply.

Comment: But by all means, @Sinatr, if you think the tag should stay, answer this question and provide a _good_ tag wiki.

Comment: @Cerbrus, it's not methodology, but [paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm). [Script languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) is a more broad term, I agree. But imho it should stay. Can you be an expert at [tag:script]? Sure, given you know many script languages and e.g. wrote own one.

Comment: Then you’re an expert at those specific languages. There’s ___always___ a more specific tag you can use than `script`... But again, put your thoughts into an answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus (the comment is mostly addressed to Sinatr, though) - I'd still get rid of the current form. It is not about the correct usage and more about misuse if you ask me. The sheer broadness of the semantics of the word "script" makes it a bad tag - if there are valid uses, we should rename it (and, agreed, give it a good wiki and guidance)

Comment: I think we should go off-[tag:scripting] as well `:)`

Comment: @iBug Oh my god! I was happy that `script` at least "only" has 400 questions. Now that is another ballpark... Well, at least that tag can be used for Sinatr's use-case...

Comment: `script` has existed as long as I've been around. I've removed it from thousands of `shell`/`bash`/`sh` questions over the past 10+ years.

Comment: How is `scripting` any better? Yikes!

Comment: I wonder how long it will be before someone writes an automated tool to prune tags they don't like, since SE Inc. has no interest in helping us curate the sewage farm that is tags. BTW, if you do write such a tool, please don't ever send it to me...

Comment: 80% of questions tagged script are new people who do not even notice the ALL_CAPS warning on [script] tooltip. Many of those are already downvoted or closed. Other ~15% should be mostly tagged [shell], and a minority ~5% refers to [script-tag] (numbers are based upon looking at first page results).

Comment: @c69 Please note that this all caps warning was only added a few hours ago. But I would still agree that 80% of the questions are new people who do not notice all caps warnings in general...

Comment: "Do not notice" is not the same as "do not read".

Comment: @iBug It's really interesting that ["script**s**" was synonymized with "script*ing*"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scripting/synonyms), but [[tag:script]] has stayed around.

Comment: The [scripts] --> [scripting] synonym [is also *ancient*, from Jun. 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLbP4.png).

Comment: @zcoop98: I was about to defend the tag, but you win. I can't defend it since scripting will work just as well.

Comment: @Lundin Only 2 questions with combined tags so I'd say it's safe to nuke `script` for them.

Comment: Complicating things, I'm guessing, is that Unity programmers call their programs _scripts_ (Unity is gaming framework programmable in C#).  I can tell from comments (and from what goes through my mind) that it rubs C# programmers the wrong way - not that there's anything really wrong with it.  I suspect that `script` looks like a shiny appropriate tag for them

Comment: @Flydog57 at best, it sounds like a "Unity-script" tag is applicable there (if it doesn't already exist). Assuming there is anything specific to code written for Unity that makes the tag relevant. If not, [<language>] + [Unity] seems enough (IIRC, you could do those in other languages than C#). I cannot see use in keeping [script] to appply to something Unity-specific, as it's just going to be misused again and again like now.

Comment: @VLAZ: I wasn't arguing to keep `script`.  I was arguing that if we keep it, it will become a shiny tag that uselessly attracts the eyes of Rep: 1 Unity programmers.

Comment: We shouldn't forget about this request; this tag is a magnet for low quality content. Questions tagged with [script] currently have [an average score of *less than 0*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1409524/average-score-of-all-questions-in-tag?TagName=script) (-0.0523 to be more precise), which I think is pretty solid evidence that something needs to happen here.

Comment: I agree that a blacklist is likely needed.  Otherwise, the tag will continue to return due to people erroneously writing language names like "javascript" and "typescript" as two words (as some people are in the habit of doing).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about JavaScript should be tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) instead
- Questions about the HTML `<script>` tag should be tagged [script-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script-tag)
- Questions about scripts in general can usually just have the tag removed, and replaced with an appropriate language tag if one isn't already in place

## Progress:

The [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=script),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscript%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscript%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscript%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscript%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=406928)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).)

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 34):

I think that we should burninate this. This could be applied to just about any question that isn't a pure algorithm or programming tool question, rendering the tag largely useless and non-descriptive.

Answer (score 11):

I think there's a larger piece that needs to be addressed here before we can burn this– once upon a time, we apparently had a [scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripts) (note the **s**) tag, and [it was synonymized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLbP4.png) to [scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting).

The tag in question, [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script), most certainly falls into the same category, and should probably be synonymized the same way, into "scripting". The only snag here are the usages that are clearly not synonymous, like for the `<script>` HTML tag, or the `script(1)` bash utility; maybe a cleanup is in order?

Just to be thorough, I'll mention that I ran across *another* other related tag, [scripting-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting-language), that maybe should get looked at too. It has less questions than "script" does right now.

---

That said, your observation about "code" and "program" above...

> It is basically like having a tag for [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code) or [program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/program)...

...still applies in the exact same manner to [scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scripting) as well; I think it's a solid point.

However, it's worth noting that this tag has a [wiki and excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scripting/info) (though maybe a poor one?), and also has a *lot* more questions, over *16,000* at time of writing, which would be a beast of a burn/ retag process. It's also noteworthy that this tag has been around since basically the beginning of the site (it appears to have been created by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260/adding-scripting-functionality-to-net-applications), with post ID #*260*, [the 64th question ever asked](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1399375/get-nth-question-posted-on-site?NumberPost=64) on Stack Overflow).

Clearly scripting is on topic here, so I guess it's really just a question of whether or not "scripting" is a useful category for sorting questions, or moreover, whether it's *not-useful enough* to warrant its removal.

To be honest.... At the end of this, I'm not sure that it's actually worth the resources to burn here. Via [@Sinatr](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr) [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406928/lets-go-off-script#comment837954_406928):

> ...[[script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) isn't a] methodology, but [a] [paradigm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm). [Script languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) is a more broad term, I agree. But imho it should stay. Can you be an expert at [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script)? Sure, given you know many script languages and e.g. wrote own one.

I'm inclined to agree that it's topical and useful as a tag, even if it should be used in conjunction with more specific tags, which makes it a poor burn candidate in my mind.

I definitely think it should be cleaned up and synonymized though.

Comment: Regarding your synonym concerns, there is already a [[tag:script-tag]] tag for the HTML tag. Regarding `script`, I couldn't really see questions about it. Most questions tagged `bash` `script` are of the kind *"Question about my bash script"* where the tag is of course completely unnecessary...

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Could be worse, awhile ago I cleaned up a bunch of [set] [value] for questions about assigning a value to a variable.

Answer (score -20):

I think there might be set some context on that before everything else.

As per original documentation the **"script" thing is clearly defined as a computer program that goes together with **html** or is embedded into it**. Source in question is the very W3C Working Group (part of the WWW Consortium, the standardization body that creates recommendations to be implemented by browser vendors and developers as well in order to display what people see in each webpage). In other words, those are the people telling to Google or Mozilla, from time to time, how to behave their Chrome or Firefox software versions when those work to render the code we write as developers. As it seems, they are the only authority in this area so probably we might listen them as well about this topic.

Strangely enough, not many answers / comments / advices / above did ever mention such thing, despite of it being accessible through just Googling "W3C script". My answer here is not implying that people writing comments or answers were entirely outside of coders group which is pity but it quite seems so. One cannot walk in a museum and not even looking at the paintings around him. Not a funny thing but mostly a sad one.

I think "script" is as useful as "jobs" nowadays. But... why compare apples with oranges though ?

**"Can be someone expert today in 'jobs'" ?** I don't think so. However, is it that one still a strong keyword, at least in search engine terms, right? People searching on Google for "jobs" might find something useful in SoF as well using that term, isn't it ? *Therefore "jobs" isn't just an internal searching term, but it's actually a gate, a tool used to bridge the searchers from Google with readers of SoF, isn't that true ?* Because StackOverFlow shouldn't be just a closed elitist platform where people think they know everything and therefore not inviting / not needing anyone / here from the outside world.

*In such a scenario this platform would slowly die and that quite soon.* By contrary, each keyword might be useful for people *really looking for stuff about that topic* instead of topics named as per opinions of people mostly living in meta level of this platform.

Despite of most people NOT being experts in "jobs", everyone is still in need and searching for these - therefore the question about being expert is **wrong** in my opinion. The implied general point is that SoF might try to gather and promote (through upvotes) the most knowledgeable people in "jobs" -- but surprise, they aren't so!! Long story short, if the expertise criteria isn't *always* working, they shouldn't be considered / enforced too heavily in some not too appropriated places or topics. Definitely not in the topic related to the scripts. But, dear fellows, please understand that (surprise),  ***THERE really ARE*** experts out there indeed in "script" topic, the people that govern the W3C body plus the people that follow their indications (some true front-end coders).

It is wrong to compare a script or some scripts with the scripting languages, as is wrong to compare a poem or a novel with the writing art. It's NOT the same! A script it's just a program, nothing else, meant to "accompany an HTML document or be embedded directly in it". It has nothing to do for example with Python (which is for back-end - which means server-side - language) or any other examples I have read above. It CANNOT apply to all languages or frameworks as someone said earlier. In computer science a language isn't the same with a library or a framework or a script or even a snippet of code. We cannot consider script so unimportant and indistinct as to wipe it out from the terms used in searching in SoF -- especially because it's the root of many terms above. The root isn't the same with branches or leaves of a tree, however we cannot speak of a tree if it has not a root from where it has grown.

The authoritative page that introduced the scripts in our lives is there since the already old html-4 (the ancestor of the actual html-5 named as just html nowadays) - link here : https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.1.
Its old age (but not only that) enforces more its value and good standing. It looks like the internet history is the "museum" I spoke about above, and the paintings are the specifications issued by that governing body.

Going forward, I think *the core issue raised by @Tomerikoo would be that "script" term isn't too narrow*. Let me answer that "history" isn't narrow enough either, however it's probably still in use, despite it's used in conjunction with WW1 or WW2 where needed, or with Roman history, at times (because those belong to historical realm, of course). However saying that "script" can cover everything, from cooking recipes to packages or else is just gross (it has NOTHING to do with such things, as it contains pure mathematics, variables, functions and everything in between).

The name of **"script" implies 'writing'** (fact that does not belong to server side programming - where we can only speak about *saving onto some file* -- opposite to ***writing on a visible surface*** as is the case with the scripts).

Most proper surface is obviously a device screen (either in a browser window - where it creates or changes html web pages, or in a console - with much less capabilities instead, or finally in a gaming application created using Unity or similar as the rendering engine for the scripts). With this one, I think I absolutely covered the **unambiguous content** concern as well.

For your "different people having different definitions" concern, that's not very true, even if some think of it as about VBScript (for desktop applications), others about JavaScript (for web apps or sometimes server generated pages) and others probably about TypeScript (last flavor of JavaScript created by Microsoft as a superset of it). No need for concerns though (as everyone asking things in SoF probably has slightly different definitions for absolutely each other topic where there are questions / answers so far). Not just that, but the good people at W3C already solidified this topic (had anyone bothered to read their beautiful and very clearly wrote specifications).

Despite of obvious free speech, I hope people not at all familiar with coding shouldn't be allowed to post in some areas or be left to decide in bulk over certain topics out of their knowledge - because that would defy the very purpose and principle of StackOverFlow - which is after all... the **expertise**, right ??

Speaking about ***dangers*** too, the main one is when allowing people (who seemingly never heard of W3C and their beautiful works in building the pillars of modern internet) to try to break such things.

Fortunately though the truth is inevitable.

**The "script" should stay -- or being reinstated if gone.** It's not some tag in html, it's the *content inside it*. It's what makes a difference between the Netscape-sque old "Hello World" pages and modern web apps of today.

*The tags are just the glue code to bind the "script" program inside the html page.*

Comment: Looks like you argue to keep the tag because of its use in HTML. We have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script-tag for that.

Comment: @rene The "script" keyword is much better than the "script-tag". While both speak about the quite same thing, the "script-tag" is only the clothing of the "script" at its core. Add to that the fact that all "tags" are small parts of html page, thing that makes somehow the "script" seem like a subordinate of the "html" which is entirely wrong. The "script" is a giant compared to a small (child size) which is nowadays the "html". All internet titans (Google, Twitter, Facebook) contributed to grow of the "script" (by creating Angular, Vue, React based on the 25 y old adult "script" grown as JS)

Comment: It sounds like you think that there are no "script"s outside of HTML and JavaScript.  You are mistaken.  A brief glance at the [questions asked in that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) makes this clear, and the comments on the question address this as well.

Comment: But the problem we're trying to solve is the misuse of the tag on questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script we're not arguing that `<script>` isn't a thing.

Comment: If anything, your answer supports my claim. I agree that script shouldn't be used for example with Python. But the fact is that it currently is used like that! Which is why it is being mostly misused and not used like you expect it to be which means it is better to get rid of it. There is a `script-tag` tag which might be what you mean but anyway a new tag should be created if needed. `script` is way too broad and vague t begin with and your answer only supports that

Comment: It's funny that most of your answer is blaming people (me) about not reading stuff and talking without any expertise when it seems like you didn't bother to read how burninations work and have a quick look at the actual questions with the [tag:script] tag. If you did do that, you might see that indeed I am not an expert but this post has 90+ upvotes so it is not about my opinion or expertise - it is about community agreement. And if you would look at the tag you will see how badly it is being used and why it serves no real purpose ***as a tag***

Comment: @Eve script isn't only JavaScript, there is so much more to scripts. We're not talking about ignoring JavaScript, in fact there are too many scripts and the scope is too broad. While I commend you for the effort writing this post, you didn't do enough research.

Comment: I'm just reading this answer thinking "what does this have to do with a tag?". You're explaining what you think "script" means and how important scripts are in todays world but I don't think that's how to defend a tag. You should argue whether or not the tag is useful. Why don't you try explaining why a question about Python tagged with "script" is better than a question without it?

Comment: You seem to be arguing about the HTML `<script>` tag (and obscuring this by calling it "W3C script"; adding to the confusion, the W3C also standardizes actual scripts, i.e. writing systems used in Unicode etc) but given what we know about the actual use of the [tag:script] tag, this actually turns into an argument for an unambiguously named tag called, let's see, `w3c-script`? Or `html-script`? No, wait, [tag:script-tag]