# Igniting fire in [space]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

This tag needs to go to the outer [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) as its very ambigous, and vague.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

This tag doesn't help to describe the question in any way. It doesn't give us any information about the real content of the question, looking at it from the home page. It can apply to many (all?) languages and be a part of many frameworks/tools/etc...

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Well... yes. It could be a `whitespace` or the `space` key or the `space` between two UI elements.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Nope, having a post tagged with [space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/space) doesn't add any meaningful info whatsoever.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Different people could use it is different context often describable better with a more specific tag.

Comment: Even the tag wiki starts with _"DO NOT USE THIS TAG!"_ You'd think they'd read that _*cough cough*_

Comment: Hey! The answer to the first criteria [looks familiar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406928/lets-go-off-script)...

Comment: :D wonder where you might have seen it!!!

Comment: Related: There is also [[tag:spaces]] which actually has a tag wiki claiming it's about the actual space character, but f course that wiki didn't save it from being misused...

Comment: So... is it a duplicate because the original one was never acted on? I mean it has a meme/joke from friggin' *Portal* in there. There's got to be a limit after which [burninate-request] meta questions age away or something...