# This tag is going out of [styles]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just saw this [Should we go off-[script]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406928/should-we-go-off-script) question.

Which made me think of another tag that should also be removed which is the [styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styles) tag.

It is stated in the tag wiki excerpt that it should not be used:

> **DO NOT USE THIS TAG**. This tag does not currently have a single, well-defined meaning. It is often used in place of, or in conjunction with, [css]. It is also used on questions about the appearance of user interfaces and questions about source code formatting.

But it seems like it *doesn't help* prevent users from using it. Just like any other tag wiki excerpt, I still see a ton of users using this tag in their posts, so is it a good idea to remove it for now? Since it is a quite broad tag like [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) or [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) and it's not very useful.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

It does describe the content of the question. However, it is not specific enough since there are lots of technologies related to the styles tag.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Yes, the styles tag is related to programming which makes it indeed suitable for the site. However...

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not really, the only information it gives is that it shows that the question is related to styling, and there are *plenty* of styling techs out there so it only provides a tiny bit of information and does not give any meaningful information.

**Can someone be an expert in [styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styles)?**

The styles tag covers a ton of different web technologies, it can range from frontend techs like [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) and [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs), To CMS tags like [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and to App development tags like [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter),
[material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-ui), to backend tags like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django)[flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask), even to the windows UI system tag [wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf), etc. So I don’t think anybody can *actually be an expert* in [styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styles).

**Is the tag harmful?**

> Sometimes, tags get in the way, add confusion, start fights, take the place of better tags...
>
> –Shog9

The tag sometimes adds confusion especially questions that are tagged with only the tag, Many users also use the tag instead of using more specific and better tags like [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css). Therefore it is somewhat harmful.

> If it looks like pointless busywork, it probably is pointless busywork...
> In particular, **if it is clear that removing the tag will do more harm than good**, then we should obviously not remove it.

Removing the tag doesn’t seem like it will do any harm in my opinion, it will only remove confusions, clear up obscurities and help ***encourage users to use better tags***.

Comment: *perhaps* it could just be synonymized into [tag:css]... I haven't looked closely at the questions yet.

Comment: I feel like we need to eradicate that usage of "*Don't use this tag*" in excerpts. Either the tag is good and we should keep it, or we should propose a burn/ clean up and deal with the problem. It's well established that the notices don't prevent people from using the tag anyway, which means it serves zero, or nearly zero, purpose to put the notice there in the first place.

Comment: [Top 4 tags used with \[styles\]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=styles): 1. [[tag:wpf]] (a UI system for Windows interfaces, ~2300 Qs), 2. [[tag:css]] (~2200 Qs), 3. [[tag:android]] (~1300 Qs), and 4. [[tag:html]] (~1200 Qs)

Comment: @zcoop98 We've had [a proposal to burn \[web\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250190/215552) for 8 years. The tag is not good. Part of my routine in the web dev tags is removing that tag. If I edit other stuff, I add the edit comment "removed tag that says Do not use this tag" to let them know. Up to them whether they read it or not, but there's no excuse if they complain.

Comment: @zcoop98 It is not feasible to do burninations of tags that have thousands or tens of thousands of uses... let alone hundreds of such tags. We just don't have the manpower. The wiki excerpts probably serve to dissuade *some* users.

Comment: @TylerH i don't think synonymizing it to css is a good idea(?) Because css is only a quite small portion of the tag, most question there isn't related to css since the tag is very broad

Comment: @zcoop98: "*Don't use this tag*" in an excerpt should be considered a temporary / stopgap measure that's better than nothing.  Something you can do while deciding on and/or organizing an effort to do something better.  We shouldn't eradicate such notes, just recognize that they're not a permanent or sufficient solution.  But sometimes it's not easy to find anything better, e.g. when sorting out a huge amount of old questions into unambiguous tags would be too much work, and mass-removing the tag entirely without replacing with other tags would be worse.

Comment: @PeterCordes Wouldn't "This tag is being considered for burnination" or "This tag is being removed" be better messaging then in that instance? At the moment, most "Don't use" excerpts are somewhat cryptic about *why* not to use, and if you're not in the know about our tag system, they give you little else to do other than ignore them; they often don't even list alternative tags. I maintain the "Don't use" messages are useless in their current form; they need better explanation and to give (an) alternative action for a given user to take instead of using the bad tag.

Comment: I Totally agree, i feel like alternative better tags are necessary  for tags with “do not use” to help the users, But i think this phrase "This tag is being considered for burnination" will not be understood by a lot of users since most of the recent questions with the tag is asked by new users, well i mean most tags with “do not use” warnings are asked by new users

Comment: Unlike Taylor Swift, some tags DO go out of style.

Comment: @zcoop98: That's a good idea to improve the phrasing, if we can decide what exactly would be better.

Comment: Well from what I see people are using the tag as a specifier, for instance `[wpf]` is quite broad and people add `[styles]` in there to specify that the question is about styling in WPF and not really about anything else, so maybe it might make sense to create a separate `wpf-style` tag and migrate all questions with `[wpf]&[styles]` tags to `[wpf]&[wpf-styles]` same with android and the other ones to CSS, if not I see no benefit in removing it

Comment: @zcoop98 Some tags like this tag: [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fixed) has some alternative suggestions in the wiki excerpt: *the more specific [css-position] or [fixed-point] tags are preferred.* but people are still using them because they are not reading the excerpt before using it so turns out "Don't use"  excerpts doesn't really help whether it is cryptic or not

Answer (score 8):

#### Yes, please burninate it!

There are many uses of styles:

- CSS styles
- React Style
- Styles in desktop applications
- Styles in Android/iPhone apps
- > Suggest me some tutorials where I can learn what are the best styles to use
  > in an application. [closed]
- and, yes, clothing. As off-topic as using the bug tag on Meta to discuss insect spray. :(

I also believe that any tag that says:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG

in its tag wiki should be removed. You're telling people not to use the tag. What's the tag doing here?

Let's **BURN**!

Comment: *"using the bug tag on Meta to discuss insect spray".* That is creative xD, you just made my day

Answer (score -12):

CSS means Cascading **Style** Sheets (therefore it is just about decorating pages using **styles**). In other words, they are exactly the same, therefore a decision might be taken probably only after comparing the total number of tags used from each one.

Because the pages are now created not just writing manually the HTML code (or the CSS inside it), this means that JavaScript files create instead the CSS part of the HTML files (in Reactjs and any other languages, even those working server side) in the same time as the presentational part (the mark-up code -- HTML in other words). Again, page styles absolutely is the same thing.

However, [style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/style) tag cannot cover the [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) tag as this one covers the part meant just for *showing the content* (like in ugly black and white simple fonts) while the CSS is like *painting it*, *animating it* and many other things (*making it mobile responsive* and so on). The same goes with Wordpress or any other CMS, where the PHP generated pages are just filled with templating parts (styles) reflected in the final HTML shown on the browser.

On the concern about being someone expert in these, there are of course people that studied CSS (and HTML prior that) that obviously are good at creating styles. (*Even someone reading free resources on w3schools or freecodecamp websites can achieve a relatively very high level of expertise on such quite simple language*).

As a conclusion, probably they should both stay, [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/style) at least until one of them gains a dramatically much more adoption than the other.

Comment: [tag:css] has 727,492 questions; [tag:styles] (a synonym of [tag:style]) has only 8,431 questions.  How is that not "dramatically much more adoption than the other"?

Comment: Also, this ignores all the other completely-unrelated-to-CSS uses of the [styles] tag that can be easily seen by [looking at the recent questions there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styles?tab=Newest).

Comment: Yes css is indeed about styling and is very related to the [styles] tag but again, the [styles] tag does not only cover [css], if you check the comment above, it says that the tags used with [styles] are `[android][css][wpf]`, so css is only a little portion of it. Also as @RyanM stated, most of the recent questions are not [css] related. In conclusion, i disagree with this

Comment: @RyanM Indeed, it's dramatically enough.
I_love_vegetables all those are about the decoration of a visible page, either on Android (mobile) or desktop. It's not anything about internal data processing. Of course, there could be also variations about how to write the css code versus how it's interpreted by the device.

Comment: "Indeed, it's dramatically enough." Then why did you say they should both stay?

Comment: if it is dramatically enough, then what does this *"at least until one of them gains a dramatically much more adoption than the other."* exactly mean?

Comment: *"On the concern about being someone expert in these, there are of course people that studied CSS"*, what about the other tags that is mentioned like `[flutter]` `[wpf` `[python]`, etc that are completely unrelated to CSS?

Comment: Could it be you are confusing what we mean with "tag" and how we use them on this site? Just in case: [When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work) and [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: *"Even someone reading free resources on w3schools or freecodecamp websites can achieve a relatively very high level of expertise on such quite simple language"* - what language? That's exactly the point that `styles` is too vague and broad. No one can be an expert in "styles". The tag as-is is not connected to any language. According to your first paragraph we shouldn't keep it because it is already covered by `css`

Comment: Doesn't CSS do more than just decorating?