# Don't read the freaking [user-manual]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I stumbled across the tag [user-manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-manual) and in conjunction with it the [user-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-guide) tag. I'm including the second tag here as well, as it is mentioned in the [user-manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-manual) tag description (emphasis mine):

> A user manual is also known as **user guide**. It is a technical communication document intended to give assistance to people using a particular system or software.

Also, [user-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-guide) doesn't have a tag description. It ironically only says

> The user-guide tag has no usage guidance.

As it stands today [user-manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-manual) has only 15 questions associated with it and [user-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-guide) has only 27 questions. In total, there are [40 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-manual+or+user-guide) affected, with 2 questions featuring both. I don't know how to handle requests for two similar tags at once, so I'm sorry if this is not the right way to do it.

### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The tags describe the content only vaguely. They appear in questions asking how to write a manual for a certain application or as a request for software suggestions regarding writing user manuals. But they're is also used when the questioner refers to the manual they've read and sometimes it doesn't have any connection to the question at all. Users seem to interpret these tags in multiple ways, so they are ambiguous.

### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No. Both tags are not about "a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers" and are therefore [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). They both describe a piece of documentation that users of a particular application can refer to when they need information about its usage.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. Both tags are very generic and only tell viewers that some kind of documentation is involved in their question. To me those tags describe an umbrella term which I'd put into the same category as the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/script) tag, which was [burninated recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406928/this-tag-has-been-scripted-out-of-existence/420832#420832). Also, as mentioned, this tag is used in questions that are off-topic or questions that even have nothing to do with documentation.

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. Both tags are used in questions that are concerned with documentation targeted at end-users, documentation for developers, excerpts of man pages, software for creating documentation.

All in all, I don't think that [user-manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-manual) and [user-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-guide) add anything to the questions that have these tags. So both tags could be burninated without affecting much.

Comment: Most usage of both tags seems to be about **creating** of user manual/guide. Such usage looks similar to [tag:documentation], so I would think about making them **synonyms** to that tag. Well, a user manual and a user guide are specific types of the documentation, but I don't think that such specific should be expressed by tags. BTW, "Both tags are not about "a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers" and are therefore off-topic" - A *tag* should not be about "a specific programming problem", a **question** should.

Comment: Do note that any tag with <50 questions, there is no need to ask for a formal burnination request, can you message the mods or high rep users in chat! :3

Comment: *"this tag is used in questions that are off-topic"* - well, the community doesn't seem to think so: [66 posts with a positive score tagged \[user-manual\] or \[user-guide\]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5buser-manual%5d%20or%20%5buser-guide%5d%20score%3a1), including [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15548023/18746959) (129 upvotes, no downvotes).

Comment: @TheThonnu but it adds no meaningful information to that post.  Is it saying that it's asking for information from the user guide?  Information that _should_ be in the user guide?  Is it saying that it's a question they encountered while reading the user guide?  The other two tags add useful information, but that one does not.

Comment: @RyanM - maybe what's needed is a disambiguation, then. If we do that, it could add meaningful information to the post.

Comment: Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344146/android-how-can-i-implement-user-manual-or-app-instruction-on-start-up-of-app) as an example. In this one, it does add meaningful information. Tagging it just with [android] would lower the quality of the post.

Comment: @TheThonnu I agree that it adds meaningful information to that post, though I'm not sure there are enough such posts to justify it.  I put my thoughts at greater length into an answer.

Answer (score 13):

These questions seem to fall into a few categories:

- Questions about documentation-generation tools.  These should be retagged [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation)
- Off-topic questions asking for recommendations for software to build a user guide or other opinion-based questions about writing user guides.  These should be closed.
- Questions about information in the user guide for a piece of software.  The tag doesn't really add any useful information here. ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50033205))  The tag should be removed from these.
- Questions about creating user guides in software.  (examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22344146), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14112031)) This could be useful; however, approximately 2 questions in 10+ years doesn't seem like it warrants a tag.
- [One question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542329/is-there-a-way-to-download-the-apache-c-standard-library-user-guide) about downloading a programming product's user guide.  This should be tagged [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual).

Overall, the vast majority of questions that are not about [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) seem to be either off-topic, way too broad/opinion-based, or not meaningfully related to user guides.  While I found two on-topic questions that shouldn't be using a different tag (there could be a couple I missed; I was skimming a bit), it doesn't seem to be enough to justify having a dedicated tag.  If there are more questions that *should* be tagged this way but aren't, that could be an argument for keeping it.

Comment: The [manual] and [documentation] tags are sketchy too.

Answer (score 9):

There is another similar tag [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual) having > 400 questions. I think [user-manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-manual) and [user-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-guide) might be made synomyms of it, but first the tag excerpt and wiki of [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual) should be improved, as it doesn't include a clear and "complete" usage guidance, it just define the term very briefly and include a link to the corresponding Wikipedia article.

Perhaps, the very first step should be to do a [cleanup](/questions/tagged/cleanup). Do we really need a tag for *documentation* as a deliverable rather than a process / tooling to generate it programmatically?

See [Ryan's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421171/1595451)

---

The requirement to be about a specific programming problem is for [questions](/questions/tagged/questions), not for [tags](/questions/tagged/tags), but tags should provide meaningful information to questions and help SME find answers about a certait on-topci subject, questions answer, questions as duplicate targets, etc., so it's fine to burninate tags that aren't helpful at all according to the scope and workings of SO.

Regarding one of the comments about make these tags synonym of another, I'm don't think that these tags should be turned into synomyms of [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) as the tag excerpt of this tag says

> THIS TAG IS FOR DOCUMENT GENERATORS ONLY. Include language and/or SDE tag as well. DO NOT USE to ask for links to documentation or tools, or to critique vendor documentation.

It might be better to make them synonyms of [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manual), but IHMHO first a [cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cleanup) should be done.

Related

- [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250933/1595451)

Comment: Making those tags synonyms is fine by me. Although not all questions I've listed above should be tagged as such. I was just under the impression that in order to use a tag in an on-topic fashion, it needs to be able to be used in an on-topic question. Hence I made the connection with the "on-topic" page. But it seems that "topic-ness" for questions and tags differ.

Comment: @QBrute Definitely there is a connection between the site scope and tags and something might be do with these tags. At the end, tags that are only used in off-topics questions eventually will automatically disappear when the off-topic questions be deleted.